# If I cancel when prompted for my Git password, I can no longer see anything I type, until I log back in

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

Everything still works (typing "exit", for instance, exits), but I can't see anything I type. There's not "funny characters", just *nothing*. Even re-running git and entering the password properly doesn't work.

How do you turn the display of typed characters back on?

Comment: try the `reset` command.

Comment: @jordanm Try making than an answer so that the readers can (after accepting) see this question is done.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks. Found this, too: http://superuser.com/a/123040/313690 (Elaborate in an answer so I can give you credit.)